# Proving a Limit using the Definition of Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt \frac{n-1}{n}$ using the definition of convergence.

Hi, I am struggling to pick an $\epsilon$ to solve this problem, I know the limit converges to 1, but I am stuck at that point.  If anyone can help with the scratch proof, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\sqrt{1-1/n}-1|\le (\sqrt{1-1/n}+1)|\sqrt{1-1/n}-1|=1/n.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. Much appreciated I can finish it from there.